# Convert Hex string to bytes in Crypto++

Tags: c++, encoding, cryptography, crypto++

I have string of hexadecimals which I need to convert to `const byte*`. I am using Crypto++ to do hashing and it needs the key to be in `const byte*` Is there any way i can convert the string of hexadecimal into `const byte*` using any of the Crypto++ libs or must i need to come up with my own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [`HexDecoder`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder) class in Crypto++.

You need to feed this characters. It seems that Crypto++ does not directly distinguish between   characters and bytes. So the following line of code supplied by varren will work:

```
string destination;
StringSource ss(source, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(destination)));    
const byte* result = (const byte*) destination.data();
```

Comment: But it will be in string. I need it to be in byte*

Comment: @user1571494 After you got string from `StringSink ss(source, new HexEncoder( new StringSink(destination)));` use `const byte* result= (const byte*) destination.data()`

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry for not taking the extra step. Background: due to efficiency and other reasons many hexencoders work on bytes instead of characters. The bytes in that case are simply ASCII/UTF-8 representations of the string so you do need to do an additional step of [tag:character-encoding].

Comment: Mistake here, the first word should be StringSource

Comment: @galinette I'm not *that* much of a CryptoPP expert. Feel free to edit; my C++ environment is down.

Answer (score 1):

> I have string of hexadecimals which I need to convert to const byte*
>   ...
>   But it will be in string. I need it to be in byte*

You should use a [HexDecoder](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder) and [ArraySink](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ArraySink) then. Something like:

```
string encoded = "FFEEDDCCBBAA99887766554433221100";
ASSERT(encoded.length() % 2 == 0);

size_t length = encoded.length() / 2;
unique_ptr<byte[]> decoded(new byte[length]);

StringSource ss(encoded, true /*pumpAll*/, new ArraySink(decoded.get(), length));
```

You can then use the byte array `decoded.get()` as a `byte*`.

You can also use a `vector<byte>`. In this case, the `byte*` is `&v[0]`. Something like:

```
string encoded = "FFEEDDCCBBAA99887766554433221100";
ASSERT(encoded.length() % 2 == 0);

size_t length = encoded.length() / 2;
vector<byte> decoded;
decoded.resize(length);

StringSource ss(encoded, true /*pumpAll*/, new ArraySink(&decoded[0], length));
```

---

> (comment) But it will be in string. I need it to be in byte*

This is even easier:

```
string encoded = "FFEEDDCCBBAA99887766554433221100";
string decoded;

StringSource ss(encoded, true /*pumpAll*/, new StringSink(decoded));
const byte* data = reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(decoded.data());
```

If you want the non-const version then use:

```
byte* ptr = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&decoded[0]);
```

Comment: But even the const is wrong, because "error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'byte *'" and "reinterpret_cast cannot cast away const or other type qualifiers". I am actually trying to accomplish something similar...

Comment: @Norbert, the non-const version would look as so. It is the only way to get the non-const pointer and avoid undefined behavior... `byte* ptr = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&decoded[0]);`.

Comment: Yes, however my result is still a hex string o.O - What I want ( thought ) I would get is bytes like so: 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 and so on.

Comment: @Norbert - Ask a new question. Reduce it to a `main` with the decoding operation.

Comment: I am not sure even how to ask the question properly T_T. What I want is to have the encoded result as 0x... etc. And then be able to decrypt it anytime. Thanks.

Comment: The wiki has lots of examples. See [HexEncoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder) and [HexDecoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder).

Comment: Yeah I was already there many times, they don't show examples like I said, They have examples from 0x... to hex string. Not the other way around.

Comment: @My bad... for not reading properly. Thanks for everything, you solved my issue in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// HEX to BIN using CryptoPP
string encoded = "FFEEDDCCBBAA99887766554433221100";
size_t length = encoded.length() / 2;
vector<byte> decoded;
decoded.resize(length);
StringSource ss(encoded, true, new HexDecoder(new ArraySink(&decoded[0], length)));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.