# Calculate RSA and save to file in HEX

Tags: c++, encryption, hex, rsa, crypto++

i'm trying to to encrypt a buffer with rsa and then save the data in hex format to file. I'm using Crypto++ 5.6.5.

Loading keys (working):

```
try
{
    // Read RSA public
    FileSource fs1("public.pem", true);
    PEM_Load(fs1, pubKey);

    // Read RSA encrypted private
    FileSource fs2("private.pem", true);
    PEM_Load(fs2, privKey, "1234", 4);
}
catch(const Exception& ex)
{
    cout << "ERROR: RSA:" << ex.what() << endl;
    SystemLog_Print("RSA: Couldn't load keys");
}
```

Encrypt (ok?):

```
std::string RSA_Encrypt(unsigned char *buf, uint8_t len)
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
    std::string plain;
    std::string cipher, recovered;

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        plain.push_back(buf[i]);
    }

    // Encryption
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(pubKey);

    StringSource ss1(plain, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, e, new StringSink(cipher)));

    // Test Decryption
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d(privKey);

    StringSource ss2(cipher, true, new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, d, new StringSink(recovered)));

    if(memcmp(plain.data(), recovered.data(), plain.size()) != 0) {
        cout << "RSA Mismatch" << endl;
    }

    return cipher;
}
```

Now i'm stuck with writing the encrypted data to a file in readable HEX like:

> AB123CDE456

Using stream operators like std::hex doesn't seem to work.
Could you give me any advice how to do this?

Not working:

```
unsigned char *buf[] = "123456789";
file << std::hex << RSA_Encrypt(buf, 9);
```

Prints only some unreadable binary data;

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't seem to work. Show your results and what you expect, as in a [mcve]

Comment: This doesn't work: file << std::hex << RSA_Encrypt(...); Only binary junk is printed to file

Comment: No, [edit] it in the question, into a [mcve]

Comment: The `std::hex` I/O manipulator is intended to modify the output of integer numbers (as text). In your case, it does nothing at best (as you want to write binary data). You have to write an own "formatter" but it's rather simple...

Comment: Also see [Convert Hex string to bytes in crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17816312/608639), [Decoding Hex Encoded Value with Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17306752/608639), [Decoding Hex Encoded Value with Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17306752/608639), [Get hexadecimal encrypted string in AES 256 Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21896874/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anyone interested...
I found a generic hex formatter here: [Integer to hex string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c)

I slightly modified it like this:

```
template< typename T >
std::string int2hex(T i)
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << std::setfill ('0') << std::setw(sizeof(T)*2)
         << std::hex << (int32_t)i;
  return stream.str();
}
```

Now i call my routines like this:

```
buf = RSA_Encrypt(data, 32);

// Write hash to sig file
for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < buf.size() ; ++i) {
    uint8_t val = buf[i];
    file << int2hex(val);
}
```

Now i get HEX chars in my file.

Comment: The Crypto++ library has most of the encoders you need. Checkout [HexEncoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder), [HexDecoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder), [Base32Encoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base32Encoder), [Base64Encoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64Encoder), [Base64URLEncoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64URLEncoder), [Base64URLDecoder](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64URLDecoder), etc...

Answer (score 0):

A hex output function could look like this:

```
void writeHex(std::ostream &out, const char *data, size_t len)
{
  char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    unsigned byte = (unsigned)data[i];
    out << digits[byte >> 4] << digits[byte & 0xf];
  }
}
```

With a small sample to test it:

```
#include <iostream>

void writeHex(std::ostream &out, const char *data, size_t len)
{
  char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    unsigned byte = (unsigned)data[i];
    out << digits[byte >> 4] << digits[byte & 0xf];
  }
}

int main()
{
  // sample data
  char data[] =
    "This is some test data:\n"
    "\x00\x01\x02\x03\0x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f"
    "\x10\x11\x12\x13\0x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f"
    "\x20\x21\x22\x23\0x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f"
    "\x30\x31\x32\x33\0x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f";
  // test writeHex()
  writeHex(std::cout, data, sizeof data);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with VS2013 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
5468697320697320736F6D65207465737420646174613A0A000102030078303405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112130078313415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F202122230078323425262728292A2B2C2D2E2F303132330078333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F00
```

The human-readable text at the begin of my test `data[]` can be checked using an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table. I simply searched for "000102" and saw the "0A" (for `\n`) before. The "00" at the end of output is for the string 0-terminator (which is considered by `sizeof` also).

Answer (score 0):

> Now i'm stuck with writing the encrypted data to a file in readable
>   HEX like:
>
> ```
> AB123CDE456
> ```

Add a [`HexEncoder`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder) and use a [`FileSink`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSink) in the pipeline:

```cxx
StringSource ss(plain, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, enc, new HexEncoder(new FileSink("file.enc"))));
```

With the change above, the data is hex encoded as it travels through the pipeline.

Later, when you are ready to read the data, you use a [`FileSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSource) and add a [`HexDecoder`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder) in the pipeline. Ad the decoder is added before the decryptor, not afterwards like when encrypting.

```cxx
FileSource fs("file.enc", true, new HexDecoder, new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, dec, new StringSink(recovered))));
```

---

You should probably avoid this because its *not* a constant time compare:

```cxx
if(memcmp(plain.data(), recovered.data(), plain.size()) != 0) {
    cout << "RSA Mismatch" << endl;
}
```

Use [`VerifyBufsEqual`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/VerifyBufsEqual) instead:

```cxx
bool equal = VerifyBufsEqual(plain.data(), recovered.data(), plain.size());
```

`VerifyBufsEqual` requires same size buffers, so maybe something like:

```
bool equal = (plain.size() == recovered.size());
size_t size = STDMIN(plain.size(), recovered.size());
equal = VerifyBufsEqual(plain.data(), recovered.data(), size) && equal;
```

---

This may help...

Instead of using an intermediate `std::string`:

```cxx
std::string RSA_Encrypt(unsigned char *buf, uint8_t len)
{
    ...    
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        plain.push_back(buf[i]);
    }  
    ...    
    StringSource ss(plain, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, enc, new StringSink(cipher)));    
    ...
}
```

You can use the `buf` and `len` instead:

```cxx
std::string RSA_Encrypt(unsigned char *buf, uint8_t len)
{ 
    ...    
    ArraySource as(buf, len, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, enc, new StringSink(cipher)));    
    ...
}
```

An [`ArraySource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ArraySource) is really a typedef of a [`StringSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/StringSource) using a constructor overload.